# Special binding in knockout that renders one template in another

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I am trying to solve a problem of rendering one template in context of another template with knockout. The outer template doesn't know and shouldn't care about the inner template and its view model. All it cares about is it's own template, a place to embed the inner template passing the name of it and its view model.

So ideally I wish I know how to implement the following binding:

```
<script type="text/html" id="outerTemplate">
    <div class="outer-template" data-bind="here: {}"></div>
</script>

<!-- ko nested: { to: 'outerTemplate', data: { name: 'I am an inner view model' } } -->

    <div class="inner-template" data-bind="text: name"></div>

<!-- /ko -->
```

If anyone knew the knockout well enough to easily outline such kind of binding I would greatly appreciate it.

UPDATE: The feature request was proposed: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a working example I made myself: http://jsfiddle.net/m34wp/4/

```
var templateComputedDomDataKey = '__ko__templateComputedDomDataKey__';
function disposeOldComputedAndStoreNewOne(element, newComputed) {
    var oldComputed = ko.utils.domData.get(element, templateComputedDomDataKey);
    if(oldComputed && (typeof (oldComputed.dispose) == 'function')) {
        oldComputed.dispose();
    }
    ko.utils.domData.set(element, templateComputedDomDataKey, (newComputed && newComputed.isActive()) ? newComputed : undefined);
}
function makeArray(arrayLikeObject) {
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0, j = arrayLikeObject.length; i < j; i++) {
        result.push(arrayLikeObject[i]);
    }
    ;
    return result;
}
function moveCleanedNodesToContainerElement(nodes) {
    var nodesArray = makeArray(nodes);
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    for(var i = 0, j = nodesArray.length; i < j; i++) {
        container.appendChild(ko.cleanNode(nodesArray[i]));
    }
    return container;
}
ko.bindingHandlers['nested'] = {
    'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var elementType = 1;
        var commentType = 8;
        var bindingValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if(element.nodeType == elementType || element.nodeType == commentType) {
            // It's an anonymous template - store the element contents, then clear the element
            var templateNodes = element.nodeType == 1 ? element.childNodes : ko.virtualElements.childNodes(element);
            var container = moveCleanedNodesToContainerElement(templateNodes);
            new ko.templateSources.anonymousTemplate(element)['nodes'](container);
        }
        return {
            'controlsDescendantBindings': true
        };
    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var outerTemplateName = options['to'];
        var dataValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options['data']) || viewModel;
        var innerContext = bindingContext['createChildContext'](dataValue);
        innerContext.innerTemplateElement = element;
        var templateComputed = ko.renderTemplate(outerTemplateName, innerContext, options, element);
        disposeOldComputedAndStoreNewOne(element, templateComputed);
    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers['here'] = {
    'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        return {
            'controlsDescendantBindings': true
        };
    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var templateElement = bindingContext.innerTemplateElement;
        if(viewModel != null) {
            var innerContext = bindingContext['createChildContext'](viewModel);
            var templateComputed = ko.renderTemplate(templateElement, innerContext, {
            }, element);
            disposeOldComputedAndStoreNewOne(element, templateComputed);
        } else {
        }
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings['nested'] = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `template` binding allows you to dynamically select the template name to use, so you can do something like:

```
<script id="outer" type="text/html">
    <h2>Outer</h2>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: tmplName, data: data }"></div>
</script>

<script id="inner" type="text/html">
    <h3>Inner</h3>
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
</script>

<div data-bind="template: 'outer'"></div>
```

In this case the view model would look like:

```
var vm = {
    tmplName: 'inner',
    data: {
        name: ko.observable("Bob")   
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

The view model could be structured however you want.  The key is just that you are passing the template name and data into the template binding.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LHhc8/

Comment: I know I can do it using the template binding, however I don't want to create a template picker function (special kind of a view model)  every time when I need to embed a different sort of content to a well known wrapper. I want to solve this problem inside the binding and never get back to it again.

Comment: Not sure that I quite follow your scenario.  Does the data itself know what template should be used to render it?  Here is a binding that enscapsulates it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/uZ8ka/

Comment: No, view model has no clue how it is going to be rendered which is, as I understand, one of the key principles of MVVM. So in your example please refrain from using the 'tmplName' property.

Comment: I guess that I am just trying to understand what logic that you intend to use to determine the name of the template that should be used with the data?  Is it hard-coded as part of the binding, is it determined by inspecting the data, or specified in another way?  I doesn't sound like what you want, but I generally do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6Gp7a/ where the view model does not know its template, but the application builds objects that have data and a template to display in the UI.

Comment: I want to get a composition of two templates. The outer one is an arbitrary wrapper with a placeholder for the inner one. Outer one doesn't have a view model associated with it, it's just a frame to be filled with data that associated with the inner one. The boundaries of the outer template indicated with the virtual control element that I called 'nested'. Inside of these boundaries there is a piece of html - this is the very inner template. The view model for the inner template is passed as the 'data' parameter of the 'nested' binding. The outer template is specified by the 'to' parameter.

Comment: In the definition of the outer template there is a placeholder. Which I suppose can be indicated as another custom binding that I called here. There are no parameters associated with that binding, so an arbitrary value can be specified for it.

Comment: Back to your last example, I truly believe that the names of the templates should not be mentioned in the view models. Instead there must be some clue, for example a key as a string. This key should be mapped to the real template name inside of the binding. Something like this: <div class="shape" data-bind={template: { name: function(shape) { return {'circle': 'circleTemplate', 'box': 'rectangleTemplate'}[shape.key] || 'unresolvedTemplate'; }, foreach:  [{key: 'box'}, {key: 'circle'}, {key: 'triangle' }]"></div>

Comment: I admit that it looks hideous, this is why there must be another mechanism to make this mapping elegant. May be something like this: <div class="shape" data-bind="template: { map: { 'circle', 'circleTemplate', 'box': 'rectangleTemplate' }, unmappedTemplate: 'unresolvedTemplate', mapKey: 'key', foreach: shapes }"></div>

Comment: Never mind, I just made one. I am not sure how well it is written, but it does the job: http://jsfiddle.net/m34wp/4/

Comment: OK- I finally understand what it is that you are trying to do.  I was not catching that you really wanted to wrap one template inside another. If you want to use anonymous template, then you would need something like what you have.  Here is a simplified approach using named templates that just extends the context to include information about the inner template: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/KemAb/

Comment: As far as my other example, in my case the outer view model is acting as a view manager and is orchestrating data with an appropriate template. The individual (actual) view models still don't know about what template that they are being rendered with. This type of thing has worked well for me, although I usually do it via require.js where my section has a name and require.js loads a view model and a template using the name as a key.